# URL variable "contains" string but should contain reference to URL instance

Tags: java

The following statement creates an instance of the URL class, fills it in the "url" variable and fills the first argument (http://www.stackoverflow.com) into a non-static attribute:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

How come it's possible to get the attribute value with the following statement, when you really should point at a get-method to get the attribute and not directly at the instance reference?:

1 What is possible but (Maybe) shouldn't be:

```
String urlstr = url.toString();
```

2 How it really should be:

```
String urlstr = url.getUrl();
```

Comment: *Why* should `toString()` 'return a reference to the class instance'? And why shouldn't `toString()` return an attribute value?

Comment: @EJP

Fixed. toString() shouldn't return a reference to the class instance, but a string. 
If you read further down the page, you'll see that I found out that the toString() method is overrided and does the same as the "toExternalForm()" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably confused because you did a println of the instance and it looks like the attribute.

The reason is that println (or string concatenation) calls the toString method of URL, which, in this specific case, reconstructs what you expect the URL to be.

Comment: Thx! The "toString()" method is overrided and is calling the "toExternalForm()" method automatically

Answer (score 2):

```
String urlstr = url.toString();
```

If you look at the source code of URL you will see that `toString()` method appends `protocol`, `authority`, `path`, `query` in an `StringBuffer` and returns the `String` representation.

By no way this means that you can access any property by calling `toString()`, if fact to access say `path` property you have to call `getPath`, `toString` just gives out a human readable format which in this case seems like the initialization parameter which you passed.

On a general note, `toString` is generally used for debug purpose where you can give out some human readable information, default `toString()` will just give you className with hashcode.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, when you do a System.out.println(a); a's toString() method is called... I'm saying that it's possible to do, just as it's possible to do auto boxing. I've unfortunately never used this method, but at least you know it's feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Here toString is doing the magic. I am not sure if implicit typecasting is possible here, but if you look in the toString method of URL, you will find that it is printing the *URL* to which this object points to.